# regular expressions in C++?

Tags: c++, regex, stl

I am looking to build a simple flex like analyzer in C++ / STL.

For that, I want to scan a string left to right and at each time extract the largest possible regular expression among a set of regular expressions.

I am not quite sure how to do that. The problem is not actually compiling the regular expressions or working with them, but I am not sure what the "higher level" loop that extracts the longest regular expression needs to be like.

Any tips would be good. It doesn't have to be explicit code, but just some pointers and ideas.

EDIT: Thanks for the pointer to boost regex library. I wasn't aware of it.

Here is an example code for extracting email addresses:

```
  std::string html = …;
  regex mailto("<a href=\"mailto:(.*?)\">", regex_constants::icase);
  sregex_iterator begin(html.begin(), html.end(), mailto), end;

  for (; begin != end; ++begin)
  {
       smatch const & what = *begin;
       std::cout << "Email address to spam: " << what[1] << "\n";
  }
```

What I want is slightly different.

For example, I would like to have an additional regex that finds http:// address and also one that finds, say, all capital strings.

```
  std::string html = …;
  regex mailto("<a href=\"mailto:(.*?)\">", regex_constants::icase);
  regex http( .... );
  regex all_caps("...", regex_constants::icase);
  // the actual definitions of the regular expressions do not matter, I can find how to do that later.


  // Here, I would like to iterate, and find concurrently the matching patterns from all three regular expressions above
  sregex_iterator begin(html.begin(), html.end(), mailto), end;

  for (; begin != end; ++begin)
  {
       smatch const & what = *begin;
       // here I should be able to identify which among the above three was found
       std::cout << "Email address to spam: " << what[1] << "\n";
  }
```

Last, I should always be able to match at least one of the regular expressions, and do it until I reach the end of the string.

Comment: Too vague.  How about some code-so-far, or pseudo code, or sample inputs and outputs?

Comment: Why not use existing tools such as Boost.Spirit.Lex or Boost.Xpressive?

Comment: I need some examples, your explanation isn't clear. I'm not familiar enough with regex'es to say this with 100% confidence, but I think the only thing which would suffice as a regex end is an invalid character. For instance, this whole comment is a valid regex. No character is illegal given the characters before it. But you don't need look-ahead.

Comment: Can't you just build a single regular expression that consists of the other three, joined with pipes `|`?

Comment: @Igor, will I be able to know which of the ones among the piped regexps is the one that had the match?

Comment: With some work. You'd have to a) add captures for them, as in `(regex1)|(regex2)|(regex3)`, and b) account for captures inside each regex, so you know which index corresponds to each top-level capture. Then, after a match is found, you would just check which sub-match is non-empty.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a set of regular expressions named A..Z.
And you got an input stream of chars.
You need to compile every regular expression (A..Z) into a state-machine (a..z).
Then you need to combine these separate state machines into a single state machine (final).
Every state in the final state machine matches a collection (1 or more) of states from the a..z state machines.
A state machine is a collection of nodes (states) and edges (input characters).
e.g. the expression "ab" matches a state machine with 3 nodes

(empty string, "a" entered, "ab" entered)

and 2 edges "a" and "b".

Similar for the expression "cd".

When you combine these two state machines you get:

(empty string, "a" entered, "ab" entered, "c" entered, "cd" entered).

Sounds feasible to attack?